# Linking Problems with css and html

Tags: html, css

So I just started using CSS but I cant figure our what's wrong with the link.

This is my code in HTML:

```
<link href 'ARandomGame.css' rel 'spreadsheet'>
```

But whenever I use developer tools to find out my problem I find this:

```
<link href="" rel="" 'spreadsheet'="" css'="" 'text="" 'ARandomGame.css'="">
```

Do you guys know at least why that happens?

The CSS part is fine, I used the same format for other html files and it worked, except for this one.

Comment: do u mean? <link href='ARandomGame.css' type='text/css' rel='spreadsheet'> having equal(assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<link href='ARandomGame.css' type='text/css' rel='spreadsheet'>
```

According to [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp):

> Link to an external style sheet:
>
> ```
> <head>
>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
> </head>
> ```

When your code, `<link href 'ARandomGame.css' type 'text/css' rel 'spreadsheet'>` is interpreted by most browsers, it thinks that:

- `href`
- `'ARandomGame.css'`
- `type`
- `'text/css'`
- `rel`
- `'spreadsheet'`

are all separate attributes without a value. Kinda like the [`checked`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_checked.asp) attribute. However, you must assign these attributes with values for consistent behavior across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ARandomGame.css">
```

See the structure below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ARandomGame.css">
</head>
<body>
    //your code....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still pretty new website designing.